# want to show reviews only for product that it belongs to

Tags: mongodb, meteor

i have two collections and i want to show reviews only for product thats been clicked , but i am getting all reviews (from reviews collection) no matter what product i click.
For adding and reading reviews i have following code in router.js

```
      // Add new review
this.route('add_review', {
    path:'/add_review/:_id',
    template:'add_review',
    data: function(){
        return Products.findOne(this.params._id)
    }
});
// Read reviews
this.route('reviews', {
    path:'/reviews/:_id',
    template:'reviews',
    data: function(){
            return Products.findOne(this.params._id)
     }
  });
});
```

**reviews.js**

```
Template.reviews.helpers({
'reviews': function () {
    return Reviews.find( )}
  })
```

**reviews.html**

```
<template name="reviews">
        <div class="row product-row">
            <div class="col-md-2">
                <img class="full" src="{{image}}">
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-10">
                <h4>{{name}}</h4>
                <p>{{description}}</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    {{#each reviews}}
        <p>{{body}} </p>
    {{/each}}
</template>
```

You can find the entire code of my project on [GitHub Repository](https://github.com/soni1/reviewIt)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After looking through your source code.  It seems you're not saving any association between products and reviews in your database. You're going to want to store the products `_id` somewhere on your review object.  Once that is done you will be able to filter Reviews by productId in your template.  I've written some example code below.

**add_review.js**

```
Template.add_review.events({
    'submit .add_review':function(event){
        var rating = event.target.rating.value;
        var body = event.target.body.value;
        if(body!=""){
            Reviews.insert({
                rating:rating,
                body:body,
                productId:Router.current().data()._id //access the product's _id here and save it in this field
            });
            FlashMessages.sendSuccess('Review Added',{ autoHide: true, hideDelay: 3000 });
            Router.go('/');

        }
        else{
            alert('Review field is empty');
        }


        return false;

    }
})
```

**reviews.js**

```
Template.reviews.helpers({
    'reviews': function () {
        return Reviews.find({productId: Router.current().data()._id}) // again, access the products _id from the router
    }
})
```

Comment: i added some more functionality and wrote some code in **includes.js** and **reviews.html** .How i can show average rating and number of reviews for the product thats been clicked? You can check gitHub repository for source code.thanks

Comment: You should make a new question to get more visibility

Comment: i have added a new question but have no got my answer yet.Can you please have a look at my question and help me. @challett